# Fetch the latest package from gitlab repository

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, dockerfile, cicd

I need to get the latest package from my gitlab repository

My repo's packages url is in this format `<BASE_URL>/-/packages/<version-id>`

And the download url as `<BASE_URL>/-/packages/<version-id>/download`

In my docker file I refer it (hardcode version) for example as:

```
ARG BUNDLE_URL="<BASE_URL>/-/packages/210/download"
RUN curl ${BUNDLE_URL} -o /app/bundle.tar.gz
```

So my question is, there is any way to download the latest version directly from gitlab, for example
to download a url like this `<BASE_URL>/-/packages/latest/download` or something similar?

Also if the above is not possible there is a way to get in the dockerfile the latest version number and put it on this url format `<BASE_URL>/-/packages/<version-id>/download`?

I need this to make the docker file more generic

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, the easiest I guess would be to use the [GitLab packages API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html). The first one lists packages from a project/a group, sorted from most recent to oldest.

If your group/project is public, you won't need any token to access the API.
Else you might provide a [Group Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) with `read_api` scope only.